What is islands/voting-prompt, and why does the question page HTML include a dedicated script tag to unconditionally log an error about it?
When I open any question page in the network, I get the following error printed in the console:

Unable to load nonexistent manifest entry 'islands/voting-prompt'. Check that your file path is correct.

It's printed by the following script tag right in the question page's HTML:
<script>console.error(`Unable to load nonexistent manifest entry 'islands/voting-prompt'. Check that your file path is correct.`)</script>

The same thing happens if I access a question page without being logged in.
What gives?
Googling for "islands/voting-prompt", the only results seem to be from resources created within the past 24 hours.
And assuming this is related, what is the file https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/islands/voting-prompt.en.js ? It seems to be regular stuff for voting prompts, and I see similar code in the full bundled js. Nothing weird at a glance. I assume "island" means a script you can include in isolation if a page doesn't use the full js? But now why is the question HTML page doing this error stuff? Is something wrong with islands/voting-prompt or its usage?
